# How to do DELETE, PUT in requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I can do a POST or GET with requests using:

```
requests.get(...)
requests.post(...)
```

How would I do a `request.PUT` or `request.DELETE` ?

Comment: Aren't you using Django on the server side to respond to these (according to your syntax, it seems like that)? Django doesn't parse PUT and DELETE methods bodies and doesn't construct dicts such as request.GET or request.POST. You can either recover the data from request.body or use POST request for PUT and DELETE and send "_method": "DELETE" in your json (as `Backbone.sync` does).

Comment: @Bob: this has nothing to do with Django. This is about the `requests` library.

Answer (score 6):

Exactly the same:

```
requests.put()
requests.delete()
```

This is documented in the [first section of the `requests` Quickstart](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#make-a-request):

> Nice, right? What about the other HTTP request types: PUT, DELETE, HEAD and OPTIONS? These are all just as simple:
>
> ```
> >>> r = requests.put("http://httpbin.org/put")
> >>> r = requests.delete("http://httpbin.org/delete")
> >>> r = requests.head("http://httpbin.org/get")
> >>> r = requests.options("http://httpbin.org/get")
> ```

One more HTTP method not mentioned in the Quickstart but supported still is [`requests.patch()`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.patch).

To produce *arbitrary* HTTP methods, use the [`requests.request()` function](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.request):

```
r = requests.request('PROPGET', 'http://example.com/webdav_site')
```